# why the checkBox is check when setChecked(false) is called

Tags: android, checkbox, onsaveinstancestate

having a few dynamically inflated/added checkbox, when some are checked the rotate or minimize the app (for easy to trigger the case, turn on the 'Dont keep activity alive'), the restored UI view shows all checkbox checked.

When os do saveInstance we store the checked items in a list, and when the OS to restore the fragment, we get the list of checked items and when re inflate the checkbox row it calls either setChecked(true) or setChecked(false) based on the list.
But after that all the checkbox shows as checked, although in the debug it clearly shows only the checked ones are used 'true' and others are used 'false' with setChecked().

Anyone experienced the same, or knows why setChecked() on the individual checkBox instance does not do what is called?

itemList = [A, B, C, D, E]

checkedListSet = [A, B]

```
void insertOneRow(ViewGroup container, Item item) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null, false);

    TextView txt = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    txt.setText(item.toString());        
    container.addView(itemLayout, container.getChildCount());

    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    if (checkbox != null) {
        boolean isChecked = (checkedListSet.get(item) != null);

        Log.i(“insertOneRow(), isChecked:"+ isChecked +", item:”+item);

        checkbox.setChecked(isChecked);  //<== trace shows only A and B are set with true
    }
}
```

item_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:checked="false"            />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"             
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the type of `checkedListSet` object? I think get method on a list only accepts an int as an index.

Comment: checkedList is just a list contains the the checked item, could be ListArray<Item> or HashSet<Item>, the checkedListSet.get(item) != null is just want to say if the item exists in the checkList then the checkBox needs to set true.

Answer (score 3):

The reason all your checkboxes are getting checked is that they all have the same `id`. If either one of them is checked and they are recreated(either because of orientation change or reattaching a fragment), Android system tries to restore their state and it identifies them based on their ids. Hence all of them get checked.

`android:saveEnabled` flag tells Android system whether to save their state and try to restore later or not.

Since you already have a mechanism in place to restore their state setting `android:saveEnabled` to false works for you.

See this question where a similar thing happens with `EditText` : [Why does Android change the value of EditTexts with same id?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20405526/3857465)

Answer (score 1):

still not sure why, but after put in android:saveEnabled="false" the same code start to work. does anyone know why it has to have android:saveEnabled="false"?

```
<CheckBox
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkedListSet.get(item) != null
```

This method will return true if there is an item in your list and it's not null.

You are assigning the result of this expression to your isChecked boolean.

Thus every time this expression returns true, your check box will be setChecked true.

I do not know what exact condition you want to check before setting the check box so i can't help you with that.

Comment: see my comment above. It is not real running code, it just try to say if the item was in the checkedList then the checkBox will be set to true.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite late but anyways .

All the above didn't work for me , I think something is wrong with that class **"android.widget.CheckBox"** .

Use something else instead like **"com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox"**.

Instead of :

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checked="false"/>
```

Use:

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checked="false"/>
```

All the function works after that.